# Finding local extrema with first derivative test

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I have a function $f:[-5,5] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous on $[-5,5]$ and differentiable on $(-5,5)$ except at $0$. I'm trying to find all the local extrema.

I know that $f'$ is $0$ at $-3,-2,4$ and undefined at $0$. The only information I have about $f$ is that
$$f(-5)=4, f(-3)=2, f(-2)=4, f(0)=2, f(4)=3, f(5)=1.5$$

I know for these problems the first derivative test is best, but we haven't gone over the first derivative test so I try to sort of "recreate" it here.

My attempt:

By the interior extremum theorem if $f$ attains a $\max$ or $\min$ on $(a,b)$ then $f'(c)=0$.

Thus we will apply this to to $(-5,0)$ and $(0,5)$ to get a list of potential local extrema. (We will also consider $x=0$ and the endpoints $x=-5,5$ since they are could also be a location of local extrema.)

First notice that $\nexists c \in (-5,-3)$ where $f'(c)=0.$ (All the points where $f' = 0$ are already given). This means that within $(-5,-3)$, $f'$ cannot change signs. (If it did then $f'$ would have to be $0$). Then if we apply Mean Value Theorem to $(-5,-3)$ we see that $\exists c \in (-5,-3)$ such that
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(-3)-f(-5)}{2}=-1$$
Thus $f'<0$ and must be decreasing. By a similar argument $f$ is increasing on $(-3,-2)$.

Then for $x \in (-3-.5, -3+.5) \space f(x)\geq f(-3)$ This is because for $x \in (-3-.5,-3)$ $f$ is decreasing so $f(-3)\leq f(x)$

And for $x \in (-3, -3+.5)$ f is increasing so $f(-3) \leq f(x).$

Thus $\forall x\in (-3,-.5,-3+.5) \space f(x) \geq f(-3)$ which means $f$ has a local minimum in $x=-3$.

Then we apply the above argument (slight tweak for local maximum) to $(-3,-2)$ and $(-2,0)$ and find that $x=-2$ is a local maximum.

Then similar story for $(-2,0)$ and $(0,4)$, we find $x=0$ is a local minimum.

Then again for $(0,4)$ and $(4,5)$ we find $x=4$ is a local maximum.

Then we can apply a similar argument to the endpoints: $(-5,-3)$. Since $f'<0 x=-5$ is a local maximum and for $(4,5) f'<0$ so its a local minimum.

So in summary local minima: $x=-5,-3,0$ and local maxima: $x=-2,4$

Could someone check if this makes sense? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't check every statement you made, but your line of reasoning is the correct approach. The sign of the derivative can only change at points where it is zero or undefined, (assuming the derivative is also continuous!) So, on intervals between those special points, the function is either non-increasing, or non-decreasing. Knowing some values of the function on that interval tells us which is the case. From that we can gain a general picture of the function, and which points are extrema.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know if the derivative is continuous in my case. All that is given is that f is continuous on $[-5,5]$ and differentiable at (-5,5) except 0. Does that fact that it is differentiable on an interval mean that the derivative is cont in that interval?

Comment: A continuous function may have a derivative which is not continuous. For example the absolute value function. However, one might say that the absolute value function is not differentiable at 0, although it is differentiable everywhere else. The term "differentiable", thus seems to me a little ambiguous. Does it mean differentiable everywhere, or are we allowed exceptions. In your case, you are actually given an exception at x=0, and that is the only exception that is given.

Comment: The way it was written is that: "f is differentiable on $(-5,5)$ except at $0$. The derivative $f' : (-5,0) \cup (0,5) \to R$ takes value $0$ exactly at $x=-3,-2,4$." Does my method work then? A big part of my argument is that on, for example (-5,-3) f' cannot change signs because if it did then f' would equal 0 somewhere in there. But that is only true if f' is continuous. At the same time though i don't know how else to do this if the way I currently did it is wrong

Comment: I think it is safe to assume that $f'$ is continuous everywhere except where it is explicitly said that $f$ is not differentiable, i.e. $0$. Long ago, I had a calculus book that defined the $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ This is definitely non-standard. With that definition, the absolute value function had a derivative even at 0. But since your problem specifically states that your $f$ is not differentiable at 0, I think it is safe to assume that discontinuities in the derivative fall into the category of $f$ not being differentiable at that point.

Comment: Doing a little research, I see that what my old calculus book defined as the "derivative" currently goes by the name "symmetric derivative".